# Cannot import files generated with f2py using Eclipse on Windows

Tags: python, windows, import, f2py

I have some Python codes developed in Linux (using Eclipse with Pydev) that recall some modules generated with f2py (which extensions are "*.so") that can be perfectly executed on this OS. Now I need to run them on Windows as well, but I'm finding some difficulties.

When, on Windows, I run a Python code that doesn't need those modules, everything is ok. But if I need to import them (for instance, "import WHATEVER", being WHATEVER.so a file generated using f2py), I receive the error "ImportError: No module named WHATEVER". These modules are in the same path that the main Python file (that is, in /projectname/src/). I've checked PYTHONPATH and I don't see anything wrong (this path is already in it).

I've also tried to import them using the command window of Python, finding exactly the same problem. It seems it is not able to open these files even when it is looking in the correct directory. Can anyone figure out what I am forgetting?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with dlls, as commented by MattDMo was a very good suggestion. However, that meant using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html), which becomes a bit tricky when the Fortran subroutine returns more than one variable (at least, for a newbe such me). Another option that worked perfectly fine for me was to make the f2py generate files with the extension "*.pyc" instead of the previous "*.so". To do so, everything is very well explained [here](http://mgaitan.github.io/posts/fortran-windows-pesadilla2.html). The advantage of this is that I don't need to modify my codes done in a Linux environment, and still run in windows.

Answer (score 2):

The `.so` files generated by f2py on Linux are specific to Linux, and won't work on other operating systems. This is why you can't run Linux binary programs on Windows, or Windows `.exe`s on Linux - the format is completely different. In order to use your libraries on Windows you'll need to compile them on Windows to generate `.dll` files. `gcc`/`gfortran` and others are available for Windows in a few different distributions. Personally I prefer [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), as its package manager/installer program is quite straightforward.

Comment: Of course, since the you are saying the program won't use the fortran libraries under Windows, you can simply make their import conditional, putting the all the import statements themselves in a `try: ... except ImportError: pass `  clause.